# Validation of Date in the past

Tags: java, validation

I need to validate that the birthdate is in the past.

I have the following form:

```
@Data
public class PersonForm {
    static final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    private Long id;
    @NotNull(message = "Name should not be null")
    private String name;
    @NotNull(message = "Date should not be null")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[.](0[1-9]|1[012])[.]((19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2})$", message = "Date format: dd.mm.yyyy")
    private String date;
    @Valid
    private List<CarForm> carForms;
```

As you can see, here I validate that the string for the date is in the right format.
I have the following entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Past(message = "Birthdate should be in the past")
    private Date birthdate;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "persons_cars",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "car_id"))
    private List<Car> cars;
}
```

and a utility method that converts one to another:

```
public class PersonFormConverter {
    static final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    public static Person toPerson(PersonForm personForm) throws ParseException {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setId(personForm.getId());
        person.setName(personForm.getName());
        person.setBirthdate(simpleDateFormat.parse(personForm.getDate()));
        if(personForm.getCarForms()!=null){
            person.setCars(personForm.getCarForms().stream().map(CarFormConverter::toCar).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
        return person;
    }
```

As you can see in my entity class Person I have a validation constraint for the field Date, but it does not work properly in my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/person")
public ResponseEntity<Object> createNew(@RequestBody @Valid PersonForm personForm, BindingResult bindingResult) throws ParseException {
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bindingResult.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(personService.createNewPerson(PersonFormConverter.toPerson(personForm)), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

If the input date is in the past the server returns error code 500, not 400. I can understand why it happens, but I can't figure out the right way to validate that my date is in the past. Could you possibly tell me what the correct variant is. I believe it must be a simple solution and I most likely am going in the wrong direction.

**EDIT:**
Here I added my creation method from my Service class:

```
public Person createNewPerson(@Valid Person person) {
    return personRepository.save(person);
}
```

Unfortunately annotation here does not help

Comment: Validation on the entity should happen in the call to `personService.createNewPerson(PersonFormConverter.toPerson(personForm))` and you'll probably get an exception if validation fails. Thus you'd need to catch that exception.

Comment: I edited my post. Is that what you were talking about?

Comment: Basically yes. Try using a try-catch block in your controller to catch validation exceptions your repository throws (and thus your service).

Comment: It worked. If you add your answer, I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(personService.createNewPerson(PersonFormConverter.toPerson(personForm)), HttpStatus.OK);
```

This line calls the service which in turn calls the repository and that performs validation and throws an exception if data is invalid. That exception bubbles up to your controller and since you don't catch it the Spring framework will do so and returns a status 500. That's because it doesn't know what the exception means so it just returns a "server error".

To return a 400 instead, you need to wrap that call in a try-catch:

```
try {
  return new ResponseEntity<>(personService.createNewPerson(PersonFormConverter.toPerson(personForm)), HttpStatus.OK);
} catch (TheValidationException e) { //don't rememer the exact name of the exception atm
  //if you can, extract information on what is invalid and tell the caller
  return new ResponseEntity<>("Invalid data provided", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```